# I have access to a planetarium, how to make a video for it?

Tags: photography, projection

I have access to a planetarium. And am very excited to try making some video that can be played inside this dome. Can you give some directions? It has about 6 projectors. I dont know what is the video format? or file format used? or how to sync it? what softwares help in this? Is everything propreitory? Is everything tied to the make and model of the machine? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ususally you'll be projecting a computer generated image, using Stellarium (free) or similar (paid) software.  Normally people with "access to a planetarium" have paid someone quite substantially for the privilege, and that person would give all the help and advice on setting up software, syncing with the hardware, etc.

Comment: So I'd start with the people who made the dome and installed the projector..